# Film video to apply to a job

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, freelancing, applications

I have a invitation to apply to a job (that I really like to have) but then they ask me to send a video explaining and talking about me. I just graduated of informatic engineer some months ago, but also I have some experience in my field. 
It's for a long-term freelance job, I think that I have the skills to work with them but I don't want to lose the oportunity for a bad and bored video.
My questions are:

- 1.-Which kind of things should I highlight?
- 2.-In what order should I say the things (about me, knowledges, experiences, etc).
- 3.-About the place that I film the video: how should it look like?  (an empty room, a wall of background, an open field? or what is the
  recomendable?)
- 4.- Which other things should I take in count to make it successfull?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do this kind of video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GuLcxg5VGuo

Comment: @MilosRadosavljevic jajajajaja!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a couple of resources that should be of use to you.

The long and short of it is if they do not provide a list of questions for which to base a script, generate your own script with typical interview questions and stick to it while being yourself.

To directly answer some of your questions:

1. I would suggest you highlight your strengths as they relate to the job you're applying for.
2. Film the interview in an area with good natural lighting, and minimal if any background noise (such as other people in the background or loud sound).
3. Be sure to use a high quality camera for the best possible video you can.  Most cell phones have HD video recording these days so that should suffice.
4. I would also prepare yourself to be patient. This exercise will take you some time (you will have to do it multiple times to get something you're comfortable with).

I have to say I am glad I have never been asked to do this. ;-)

Additional resources with great detail below:

[UnderCover Recruiter](http://theundercoverrecruiter.com/successful-video-interview/)

[Montage Talent](https://www.montagetalent.com/video-interviewing-resources/quick-guide-job-winning-video-interviewing)

[Michael Hyatt](https://michaelhyatt.com/how-to-record-a-video-interview-in-eight-steps.html)

Comment: No problem, and good luck to you!